# Very dark webcam on new HP DV7

Tags: laptop, webcam, brightness

I just got my new HP DV7 6135dx about a week after it came out and when I was playing around with the webcam a few days after, it worked great.

But then all of a sudden it went dark. Not black, but just very dark. I have tried

- uninstalling and reinstalling the webcam through the device manager
- rebooting multiple times
- alternative webcam software to the one HP has pre-installed (Cyberlink YouCam) thinking I might have tweaked a wrong setting in there

but I was still getting the same dark picture. Is there anything I can try to do before I take it down to Best Buy and have geeksquad take a look at it?

Comment: try this, i had the same problem and it fixed mine :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lquWomWd3d4